# Simulate Altitude Position in Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, altitude

I am trying to simulate altitude of position in Android Emulator. As I saw in old tutorial, Android Emulator did support to emulate Altitude, but for the currently version they didn't. Is there anyway to simulate altitude?
The following image is what I got in Android Emulator.

[image]